Create multiple accounts from one seed using Python solders library
I want to create multiple accounts related to a seed derived from one mnemonic.
What I want to achieve is to import multiple Solana addresses from one mnemonic, looking like this (not my wallet):

This is what I tried so far but when I import the wallet from the mnemonic, only one Solana address to import is shown:
from solders.keypair import Keypair
from mnemonic import Mnemonic

mnemo = Mnemonic('english')
mnemonic = mnemo.generate()
seed = mnemo.to_seed(mnemonic)

num = 5

for i in range(num):
    print(f'Generating wallet {i}/{num}')

    path = f"m/44'/501'/{i}'/0'"
    keypair = Keypair.from_seed_and_derivation_path(seed, path)
    public_key = keypair.pubkey()

    ...

The solders API documentation does not quite help me either.
Thanks in advance.

The solders library might not directly support deriving keys from a mnemonic using the exact BIP44 path format out-of-the-box. Instead, you can try to use the bip32 and bip39 libraries to derive the seeds and then create keypairs for Solana.
try looking into these repositories:
=> https://github.com/trezor/python-mnemonic
=> https://github.com/kevinheavey/solders

These are the exact libraries I'm using in the example.

This was meant as a comment from answer of Hawa Kallon

In your code example, you're only changing one part of the path. If you want to mimic what Phantom shows, you might want to go through all of their derivation paths, which are documented at https://help.phantom.app/hc/en-us/articles/12988493966227-What-derivation-paths-does-Phantom-wallet-support
So you can also check:
m/44'/501'/0'
m/44'/501'/1'
m/44'/501'/2'
...

And
m/501'/0'/0/0
m/501'/1'/0/0
...

Etc etc

from solana_account_sdk.api import format_mnemonic

words = 'cream bleak tortoise ocean nasty game gift forget fancy salon mimic amazing'

format_account = format_mnemonic(words)
print(format_account)

format_account_1 = format_mnemonic(words, _dpath="m/44'/501'/0'/0'")
print(format_account)

format_account_2 = format_mnemonic(words, _dpath="m/44'/501'/1'/0'")
print(format_account)

